# Random variable probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

On probability space $\Omega$ with elements a,b,c,d,e. Define $\sigma$-algebra $F$ on $\Omega$-collection of subsets of $\Omega$ and $H=X+Y$.

Probability measure by P{a}=P{b}=P{c}=P{d}=1/5,RV X,Y:

X{a}=1, X{b}=-1, X{c}=1, X{d}=-1, X{e}=1,

Y{a}=1, Y{b}=1, Y{c}=-1, Y{d}=-1, X{e}=-1

I need to derermine $\mathbb{E}[H|X]$.

Here is my attempt -

I suppose that  H{a}=2, H{b}=0, H{c}=0, H{d}=-2, H{e}=0.

For $\int_{[a,c,e]} H(w)d\mathbb{P}(w)= H(a)\mathbb{P}(a)+H(c)\mathbb{P}(c)+H(e)\mathbb{P}(e)=(-2)*1/5+0*1/5+0*1/5=-2/5$

$\mathbb{E}[H|X](a)=\mathbb{E}[H|X](c)=\mathbb{E}[H|X](e)=-2/5*5/3=-2/3$

For $\int_{[b,d]} H(w)d\mathbb{P}(w)$= $H(c)\mathbb{P}(c)+H(d)\mathbb{P}(d)=0*1/5+(-2)*1/5=-2/5$

$\mathbb{E}[H|X](b)$=$\mathbb{E}[H|X](d)=-2/5*5/2=-1$

I think that the way of thinking is right. But I am confused with this operation $H=X+Y$. Did I define it right?

Answer (score 0):

Note: You need to use conditional probability measures.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[H\mid X{=}{-}1] ~= & ~ \int\limits_{\{b, d\}} H(\omega)\operatorname d \Bbb P(\omega\mid \omega\in\{b, d\}) \\[1ex] = & ~ (0-2)\cdot\tfrac 1 2 \\[1ex] = & ~ -1
\\[4ex]
\mathsf E[H\mid X{=}1] ~=&~ \int\limits_{\{a,c,e\}} H(\omega)\operatorname d \Bbb P(\omega\mid \omega\in\{a,c,e\}) \\[1ex] ~=&~ (2+0+0)\cdot\tfrac 1 3 \\[1ex] ~=&~ \tfrac 2 3
\\[4ex] \mathsf E[H\mid X] ~ = & ~ -1 \raise{0.5ex}\chi_{\{b,d\}}~+~\tfrac 2 3\raise{0.5ex}\chi_{\{a,c,e\}}\end{align}$$

---

As a reality check: $\mathsf E[H\mid X] ~=~ \mathsf E[X\mid X]+\mathsf E[Y\mid X] ~=~ X + \mathsf E[Y\mid X]$